# How to detect if the webview already load my desired page

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, anime.js

I want to get the image url in https://www1.kickassanime.rs

So I use some code to extract it, I put my code on webview1 finished loading.
So that when the webview1 finished loading the image url from site automatically load to imageview on android.

But the site kickssanime, I dont know how to say it, please check the site,
You will see a blank page first and then their homepage. It seems the webview already finished loading but their homepage is not yet rendered, please check the site.

I want to get the first image url automatically
when webview finished  loading the site.
I have already the code to grab the image url from the site,

(my question)
I want to know what code to add so that my app detect, if the webview already load my desired page.

I wont add my code since my question is logical problem

Comment: Have some delay before calling the grab code

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in your activity/fragment class add

```
 private boolean isPageLoaded = false;
```

then

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
         
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    if(!isPageLoaded){
                        isPageLoaded=true;
                       
                    }

                }
            }


        });
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(Url);
```